# How do I talk to the spider?

Tags: chicory

There is a singing spider in a Supper Woods cave that doesn't speak my language and appears to have unending dialogue options. How do I communicate with it or what am I supposed to do with it?

[image: spider]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will come later, though story progression

> There is a quest later that will help translate the language [image: acquiring the translator]

> Another quest later will involve delivering a letter to this spider [image: a letter for the spider]